# Node.js runtime equvalent of npm list?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I'm running a Node.js Express web server in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I wish to list the active node module versions on a special Admin About page.

Is there a function I can call on to list the detail I would typically get from `npm list`?

For example:

```
├── async@0.9.0
├─┬ aws-sdk@2.1.17
│ ├─┬ xml2js@0.2.6
│ │ └── sax@0.4.2
│ └── xmlbuilder@0.4.2
├── crypto@0.0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `npm` programatically:

```
var npm = require('npm');

npm.load({}, function(err) {
  npm.commands.list(function(modules) {
    console.log(modules);
  });
});
```

Remember to install it locally first: `npm install npm`.

Comment: Your npm.commands.list() callback is missing an `err` but I most assuredly got the gist of it. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to call any command line instruction from inside node. You can also add options to the instruction. For example to receive the [npm list](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) data as json:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
list    = spawn('npm', ['list', '--json']);

list.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('json npm list: ' + data);
});

list.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('there was an error retrieving npm list: ' + data);
});

list.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```